# How to test props after being assigned to new variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I'm trying to test an `if` condition with props. It works fine if I pass in `this.props.thingToTest` but if I assign something like `const propsVariable = this.props.thingToTest` and test the `if` condition, I won't get code coverage.

I've tried passing in the const as props in my shallow wrapper, or declaring the const in the test but it still doesn't see it.

Component code:

```
render() {
    const propsVariable = this.props.thingToTest;

    if (this.props.otherThingToTest === 'test') {
      return <Component />;
    } else {
      if (propsVariable) {
        return <OtherComponent />;
      }
    }
  }
```

Test code:

```
const props = {
  propsVariable: {}
}

it('tests else condition in render method', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<OriginalComponent {...props} />);
    const instance = wrapper.instance();
    jest.spyOn(instance, 'render');
    instance.render();
    expect(instance.render).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

I expect the else case to get hit and return `<OtherComponent />` but it doesn't hit the else case at all.

If I  put `otherThingToTest` in the props object in my test it'll hit the first `if` case fine, but because my other prop `thingToTest` is assigned to a variable, it won't hit the else case and I'm not sure how to test that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have not passed `thingToTest` props to the component in Test code, `propsVariable` will be assigned undefined.

```
const propsVariable = this.props.thingToTest; // propsVariable = undefined
```

That's why code will not take the `if` path inside the `else` block and hence `return <OtherComponent />;` statement will not covered.

So you need to just pass `thingToTest` props to the component in Test code and it will work fine.

```
const props = {
  thingToTest: 'someValue'
  // passing propsVariable: {} won't work
  // since it will be available as 
  // "this.props.propsVariable" inside the 
  // component 
}
```

Note: `else` case will hit if you don't pass `otherThingToTest` props.